# in public or at public

Tags: prepositions

Apparantly both version are in use according to Google Books Ngram. However, the use of **in public** far more common than **at public**.

I wonder if saying **at public** is wrong or non-standart English even though it is in use.

For example :

> Smoking in/at public should be forbidden.

[Google Books Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20public%2C%20in%20public&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20public%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20public%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I have never come across *at public* unless it's used as an adjective, as in: *at public libraries/schools* etc

Comment: Beyond the Ngram, you should search for some actual examples using the phrase, and add to your question. An Ngram by itself does not consider context.

Answer (score 5):

I don't suppose you clicked on the links below the ngram that show the actual hits?

If you [peruse the found instances](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22at%20public%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), you can see that "at public" is used when *public* functions as an adjective, in phrases like *public schools*, *public meetings*, or *public parks*.

So, you would **not** say:

> *Smoking at public should be forbidden*.

but you might say:

> *Smoking at public events should be forbidden.*

Comment: When I google the phrase "smoking **at** public places" verbatim (in quotation marks), I (mostly) get results from authors/websites related to India, Pakistan, and some African countries — the dialects of which I'm not accustomed to, as it were. "Smoking **in** public places" yields more results and, not least, they're in *Englishes* I was taught to regard as standard. Would "in" be your choice of preposition as well?

Comment: "Smoking *in* public" is the common idiom, or sometimes "Smoking in public spaces".  J.R. is correct that "at public events" is fine, but I think this is because the preferred idiom is "at events" or "at an event".  It doesn't matter if they are public or private.  Ex: You would say "smoking in a public park", because you would otherwise say "in the park".

Comment: @Andrew I concede that the *spaces* version sounds even better, but Google Ngrams Viewer shows significantly more hits for the *places* one, for some reason.

Comment: @user2684291  "Public places" is fine too.  I think my mind got fixed on "spaces" because that's what we've been talking about.  In any case my point is that the preposition matches the noun ("**in** places") and not the adjective "public".

Answer (score 2):

The usual term is

> Smoking **in** public.

when one is surrounded *by the public*.

Conceivably,

> smoking **at** the public

might be aggressively blowing second-hand smoke at passersby similar to "shooting at the public", but the action would still be "in public".